# Update libpq5 (>= 9.4~beta3) on Debian Wheezy

Tags: linux, postgresql, debian

I want to upgrade my postgresql version, native 9.1 from debian wheezy to last 9.4 version.

I put the line

```
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ wheezy-pgdg main
```

into

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
```

then

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

But when I try to apt-get install postgresql-9.4, I got the following error:

```
postgresql-9.4 : Depends: postgresql-client-9.4 but it is not going to be installed
```

So I try to install postgresql-client-9.4 and I got the following error:

```
postgresql-client-9.4 : Depends: libpq5 (>= 9.4~beta3) but 9.3.5-1.pgdg70+1 is to be installed
```

And I really don't know how to upgrade libpq5...

Thanks for help

Comment: You need to run `apt-get update` to update the package index - `upgrade` upgrades your currently installed packages.

Comment: I forgot to said it but I did too

Comment: I got the same problem, `apt-cache policy libpq5` does not show 9.4 version as available. Got any success?

Answer (score 1):

You have to append **9.4** to repository line. From http://www.postgresql.org/about/news/1524 :

> If you are using one of the release distributions of Debian or Ubuntu,
>   add this to your /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list to have 9.4
>   available:
>
> deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ codename-pgdg main 9.4